# Docker - Xdebug debug PHP CLI script (VS Code)

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, magento2, xdebug

This question is *regarding getting Xdebug to work with a CLI PHP script hosted inside a web-server Docker instance*.

I have docker containers : `web-server`, `varnish-cache`, `nginx-proxy`.
I am able to successfully debug a Magento 2 web-page via browser with this VS Code Launch config:

*This is with the new XDebug v3 which removed alot of v2 configuration settings*

**Client (Windows 10) IP (my laptop) : 192.168.1.150, Host (Ubuntu 20.04) IP: 192.168.1.105**, hosting with Docker containers IP: `172.100.0.2-5`

**VS Code launch:**

```
 "name": "(Magento 2) Listen for XDebug on 192.168.1.5/105",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9099,
            "stopOnEntry": false, // Set to true to test any script on entry
            "log": false,
            // Remember to update remote_connect_back or remote_host
            // inside xdebug PHP configuration.
            // When using CLI debugging - rather use remote_host,
            // because remote_connect_back = 1 does not work with CLI
            // Server -> Local
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceRoot}",
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_children": 10000,
                "max_data": 10000,
                "show_hidden": 1
            }
        },
```

**XDebug configuration (PHP 7.3)**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.client_port=9099
xdebug.client_discovery_header=HTTP_X_REAL_IP
xdebug.discover_client_host=On
; fallback for CLI - use client_host
xdebug.client_host=172.100.0.2
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.mode=debug
```

**Docker network:**

```
docker inspect network magento2-network-frontend:
        "Containers": {
            "6538a93fbe811fbbd9646d4ce089e1b686b508862ed86f6afaac1b600043a1e5": {
                "Name": "redis-cache-magento2.3.5",
                "EndpointID": "d27bfbff61765cf2b840e98d43ec7a378e182baa7007dabde4bab5a41734fa2a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:64:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.100.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7c7ba745db17d6d6a100901ed1e3fe38a3d26a97e086edc155254a7d41033bcf": {
                "Name": "web-server-apache2-magento2-3-5",
                "EndpointID": "9b81f6b7ff2292eba6fb68af209f1d5c958bea3ee0d505512862f225ed8e57be",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:64:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.100.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7f208ecce2aafdf182e4616ef2e8b043f3b8245018c299aae06c1acf4fc0d029": {
                "Name": "varnish-cache-magento2-3-5",
                "EndpointID": "e1c4e3f9e792b7dfd2cebfbb906bd237795820639a80ab8f530f0c8418257611",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:64:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.100.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "dc599fa93b09650b70f8f95333caecc8f9db18cd19b17be57d84196e91f54c2a": {
                "Name": "nginx-proxy-magento2-3-5",
                "EndpointID": "7b8396af676d9af51b098d09f20d9e73ef83f4b085cb5f7195ea234aae7ed91d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:64:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.100.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
```

The CLI command: _as can be seen it's a Magento 2 `bin/magento migrate:data` command from *within the hosting Apache2 Web-server Docker container*. (IP shown above is then : `172.100.0.2`)

```
rm var/migration* && bin/magento migrate:data /var/www/html/app/code/ModuleOverrides/Magento_DataMigrationTool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.7.0.2/config.localboth.host_restoredb.xml
```

No debug breakpoints will work in my VS Code on Windows 10 Client (IP 192.168.1.150) because I am calling the script from within the container `172.100.0.2`.

The log file `/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log` confirms something along this line:

```
Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 172.100.0.2:9099 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

So, since I have no idea how to run a CLI script from Windows 10 client and only from within Docker container, how/what can I do to get this CLI script to connect to Xdebug?

**Additional information (if needed)**

Magento 2 has CLI capability `bin/magento [command]` - and the command I am trying to debug is part of the `data-migration-tool` which is failing to import attributes correctly.  *No-one has a 100% working solution on the github repo for this particular issue - so I want to try and dig deeper to try and find a solution*. Also, the tool is **only a CLI tool, no web-ui option**.

Comment: Please tell me if there is any other information that is required.   I would really like to get this resolved, for now but also because I would need to debug CLI scripts in the future.

Comment: I never thought this is such an impossible request, thousands of PHP developers, and no-one can answer how to get xdebug to work with a CLI script with Docker.  Please guys :) someone here please assist!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set Xdebug's `xdebug.client_host` to the IP address of your IDE, which you indicated is `192.168.1.150`.

You also need to turn off `xdebug.discover_client_host`, as that would try to use the internal Docker network IP (`172.100.0.2`), which is not where your IDE is *listening* on.

Remember: Xdebug makes a connection to the IDE, not the other way around.

Comment: Well, I just discovered that I have been concentrating on the wrong thing... I didn't understand that xdebug will forward the the connection from `172.100.0.2:9099` (which was the docker connection the xdebug continued to complain about not being able to `connect to`...) to my IDE `192.168.1.150:9099`.  Important information for others.  _The error output of xdebug confused me and thought I should make the xdebug connection work with `172.100.0.2:9099` but it turns out your solution worked.  If ok, I will add additional information to your answer that might help others.

Comment: I added additional important information to the answer (there were additional things to consider) _in conjunction to your additional answer._

Comment: Yes, the error information from xdebug log files had me thinking its the other way round.  I only realized the inverse on your answer.... because I had to make sure to see _why_ your answer _should work_.  Thanks again!

Comment: My edits were not accepted, I assume because it was your bounty, the system does not allow for me to add info.  This might only be related to Magento specifically, but others might find this useful for troubleshooting.
Can you please add the fact to run `php bin/magento some:command` and _not_ `bin/magento some:command` _even though `bin/magento` is a PHP script and runs **fine just like that when not debugging CLI**.  Breakpoints didnt work on CLI with Docker to my IDE without explicitly calling `php ` in front of command.

Comment: I think that's a Magento specific thing? It's possible it starts PHP without an ini file or something like that? It's certainly not something that Xdebug does care about.

Comment: Yes, thats the thing: I am not sure; but somehow in my instance Xdebug doesn't debug anything in Magento.  It must be something related to that. In any case very confusing (to troubleshoot and get working) and strange.  Thanks for advice